# css full width height fixed scrollable container

Tags: css, html

I load a div thanks to pushstate history and I want to display it by sliding the div from the bottom to the top.

For the sliding animation I use css3 transition triggered with jquery addclass.

However, I have a lot of difficulties to obtain a full screen fix div container. This container must be scrollable also.
The container doesn't fill all the screen with this css:

```
html, body{
    position : relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-heigth: 100%;
}
#ajaxify_container {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
} 
.ajaxify_container-animated {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);   
}
```

Sorry for my English, I'm French

Comment: Could you leave  code on codepen.io, jsfiddle.net or liveweave.com . So we have HTML+CSS to check on :) (vive le vin , le fromage et le bon pain :) )

Answer (score 0):

Actually min-height in html/body is useless, it should be height if you want to use min-height for #ajax-container.

Beside, position:fixed refers to screen window. height100%; + width:100%; + overflow:auto; is plenty enough to fill the window and see it scroll if needed.

Your fiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/j2Yqc/4/

```
#single-container {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding:5px;
    background: rgb(33,35,37);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. But I still have a problem. My ajaxify_container have a background and it doesn't fill the entire div. But now the container fill the page and can be scroll...

Comment: Just set a min-height:100%; to main container inside #ajax-container. No need to load a full html page, just content, it is not a frame :)

Comment: It's not working. If I set a min-height for my ajaxify container I have same problem at the beginning. I can't see the header of my ajaxify container if the content have a height higher than body...

Comment: oky, i t's getting confusing. can we have a fiddle or similar  (FR- c'est possible de voir en ligne tes essais sur : au choix: codepen.io, jsfiddle.net or liveweave.com )

Comment: I made a fiddle but it's working in the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/j2Yqc/2/  My problem is the background fill 100% window height, but when I scroll, there isn't background after...

Comment: okay , it has to do with defaut margin, (fusion de marges , if you know how to call this in english, it'll be useful for others). So the trick is to set a padding : http://jsfiddle.net/j2Yqc/4/

Comment: i see no problem, bg comes from top to bottom where it scrolls. Wich browser ?

Comment: If you resize the window you will see the problem. For me it's not working on chrome and IE and on touch device. I have big problem with the background and scrolling...

Comment: I fix near all the problem by adding `overflow-y: scroll` to the single container : http://jsfiddle.net/j2Yqc/5/ . But it really buggy in IE9 . It's more complicated than expected...